# mail() function not send more than 1mb attachment in php

Tags: php, html, email

i try to send mail with attachment .zip or .rar file, but i cant send more than 1mb file.

```
  $to ="jignesh.tplabs@gmail.com";
  $fromEmail = $_POST['email']; 
  $subject = $_POST['name']; 

  /* GET File Variables */ 
  $tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
  $fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
  $fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

  /* Start of headers */ 
  $headers = "From: $fromEmail ";

  if (file($tmpName)) { 
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'r'); 
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
  fclose($file); 

  /* a boundary string */
  $randomVal = md5(time()); 
  $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x";   

  /* Header for File Attachment */
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
  //  $message . "\n\n"; 

  /* Encoding file data */
   $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));  

  /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
  $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
   $data . "\n\n" . 
   "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
  }
```

$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers" );

if($flgchk){
    echo " alert('Mail Sent'); window.location.href = 'index.html';"; }
else{
echo " alert('Mail Sending Failed .'); history.back(); ";
}

Comment: Check your php.ini configuration you should find an option with a name like max file size

Comment: This code run on my server how can change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tsup. this might be of some help.
chunk the data to 1MB and start the php mail function to send 1 MB in every 1 min with sleep ( int $seconds ).

Also, you need to know what is the value of max execution time provided by your hosting provider in the php.ini file.

It is well explained in this website link. check it out.

http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/278251-php-mail-attachment-max-size